# wmv file not working in Firefox 3.0.3, Its working fine in IE

Tags: firefox

I am using following code to embed files, video with `.wmv` extension, that is not working in Firefox. It's working fine in IE.

```
document.getElementById("QuestionMedia").innerHTML += 
  '<OBJECT ID="MediaPlayer" WIDTH="350" HEIGHT="280" CLASSID="CLSID:22D6F312-B0F6-11D0-94AB-0080C74C7E95"STANDBY="Loading Windows Media Player components..." TYPE="application/x-oleobject">' + 
    '<PARAM NAME="FileName" VALUE="video/' + Question.Media + '">' +
    '<PARAM name="autostart" VALUE="false">' +
    '<PARAM name="ShowControls" VALUE="true">' +
    '<param name="ShowStatusBar" value="false">' +
    '<PARAM name="ShowDisplay" VALUE="false">' +
    '<EMBED TYPE="video/x-ms-wmv " SRC="video/' + Question.Media + '" NAME="MediaPlayer" WIDTH="350" HEIGHT="280" ShowControls="1" ShowStatusBar="0" ShowDisplay="0" autostart="1"> </EMBED>' + 
  '</OBJECT>';
```

Please let me know what would I do to make it work..?

Comment: Downvote for sloppy formatting and orthography -- kidding, but just so.

Comment: What are you feeding innerHTML with?

Answer (score 1):

You should have the [Windows Media Player Plugin for Firefox](http://port25.technet.com/pages/windows-media-player-firefox-plugin-download.aspx) to be able to see the video. WMV is a Microsoft/Media Player specific format and needs a plugin for the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you have the video player object in the file and set it's SRC using JavaScript? That would be a [dirty] work-around if it's doable and you can't find the answer to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I came across some one who had the problem in reverse - here was what worked for them in Firefox - it also worked for me in bith IE7 and Firefox.

Code is below:

```
<!-- begin embedded WindowsMedia file... -->
<table border='0' cellpadding='0' align="center">
  <tr><td>
    <OBJECT id='mediaPlayer' width="704" height="573" classid='CLSID:22d6f312-b0f6-11d0-94ab-0080c74c7e95' codebase='http://activex.microsoft.com/activex/controls/mplayer/en/nsmp2inf.cab#Version=5,1,52,701' standby='Loading Microsoft Windows Media Player components...' type='application/x-oleobject'>
      <param name='fileName' value="../content/Video/video.wmv">
      <param name='animationatStart' value='true'>
      <param name='transparentatStart' value='true'>
      <param name='autoStart' value="true">    
      <param name='showControls' value="true"> <param name='loop' value="true">
      <EMBED type='application/x-mplayer2' pluginspage='http://microsoft.com/windows/mediaplayer/en/download/' id='mediaPlayer' name='mediaPlayer' displaysize='4' autosize='-1' bgcolor='darkblue' showcontrols="true" showtracker='-1' showdisplay='0' showstatusbar='-1' videoborder3d='-1' width="704" height="573" src="../content/Video/video.wmv" autostart="true" designtimesp='5311' loop="true">
      </EMBED>
    </OBJECT>
  </td></tr>
<!-- ...end embedded WindowsMedia file -->
<!-- begin link to launch external media player... -->
  <tr><td align='center'>
  </td></tr>
</table>
```

You would need to change the dimensions of your player to fit your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use one of the available Open Source, thus free, open source solutions to embed the movie in the page.

This will solve the potential plugins problems (except the required Flash Player obviously) and work on any platform or browser.

titel

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar problem with Firefox 3 on the PC.  When I changed

```
<embed src="/media/video.wmv">
```

to

```
<embed src="http://mysite.com/media/video.wmv">
```

the problem suddenly went away for me.  Go figure.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the VideoLAN plugin try uninstalling it. It has caused me nothing but trouble.