# Why opens the embedded real player plugin on Firefox a external window?

Tags: firefox, wmv, realplayer

I'm playing something around with the realplayer. I'm try to embed the realplayer in a web site. I try to play a wmv video with Firefox (version 22). I use following code:

```
<OBJECT CLASSID="clsid:CFCDAA03-8BE4-11cf-B84B-0020AFBBCCFA" HEIGHT="722" ID="RVOCX" WIDTH="1279">
        <PARAM NAME="SRC" VALUE="5403.wmv"/>
        <PARAM NAME="controls" VALUE="imagewindow"/>
        <PARAM NAME="console" VALUE="video"/>

        <EMBED height="722" width="1279" src="5403.wmv" 
    type="audio/x-pn-realaudio-plugin" 
    controls="imagewindow"
            console="video"
            autostart="true"
    >
        </EMBED>
      </OBJECT>
<br />
      <OBJECT CLASSID="clsid:CFCDAA03-8BE4-11cf-B84B-0020AFBBCCFA" HEIGHT="100" ID="RVOCX" WIDTH="400">
        <PARAM NAME="SRC" VALUE="5403.wmv"/>
        <PARAM NAME="controls" VALUE="imagewindow"/>
        <PARAM NAME="console" VALUE="video"/>

        <EMBED height="722" width="1279" src="5403.wmv" 
    type="audio/x-pn-realaudio-plugin" 
    controls="all"
            console="video"
            autostart="true"
    >
        </EMBED>
      </OBJECT>
```

But every time if a video should be started a external realplayer window is open within a dialog message box with the message "For this content no software update are available" is shown. After closing this dialog the video can be played in the external window.

But that is not what I want. I want to play the video in the embedded browser area.

Anybody has an idea?

Thanks,
Steffen

Comment: possible duplicate of [wmv file not working in Firefox 3.0.3, Its working fine in IE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/295839/wmv-file-not-working-in-firefox-3-0-3-its-working-fine-in-ie)

Comment: Last year I had evaluate the RealPlayer plugin as a alternative to the WMP plugin. So this is not a duplcate of the other question ...